# need to run cython version of a t-sne program - confused

Tags: c, cython

I have a very large dataset and the scikit-learn version of t-sne crashes. So, I found a package on github called bhtsne that looks like it will get the job done: https://github.com/dominiek/python-bhtsne

Here's my question. I pip installed the package and it's running. Five hours so far! But it doesn't seem like it's using cython, which I *think* is the point of this package.

Here is my stupid question:  How do I tell the system to use cython?!?!?  Or maybe more basically - what do I need to do to get this package working with cython so it will run faster? Thanks for any help. I'm on a mac using anaconda and jupyter notebook.

Comment: If the code was not originally written with cython, then the only way is to rewrite the code yourself in cython. A quick look at the source code of your posted github link shows me that it is indeed partially written in cython. See https://github.com/dominiek/python-bhtsne/blob/master/setup.py#L14

Comment: yes, it's written in cython. that's why i chose that program. But how do I tell my system to use cython??? I have never used cython before. Pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: As a user you don't need to do anything, if the package has been installed properly (for example with pip), then the python interpreter will know which shared libraries it has to read. In your code you just do `from bhtsne import tsne`. and the python interpreter will take care of the rest.

Comment: Did you jump into using this new package with the big problem that caused scikit to 'crash' (are pretty useless description)?

Comment: crash=kernel died.  meanwhile bhtsne still running. so maybe the cython helps it run, but not very fast...

Comment: You might be able to confirm it with something like this https://superuser.com/questions/310199/see-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux. You'd look for .so files associated with btsne. That said, I think it has to be using Cython if it's running at all.

Comment: yeah. it's running. by watching what it's doing in the terminal window, I can see where it is. Also, a test on a small test dataset shows it's much faster than scikit t-sne.